# Facebook SDK Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, facebook

I uninstalled my app and reinstall it though ADB and now none of the facebook stuff works. The code is exactly the same as before but it just gives me the following error:

(BTW the code is identical to the Android tutorial stuff, for testing of course).

Following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.polygonattraction.lovebirds/com.polygonattraction.lovebirds.facebook.FacebookLoginTest}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

It seems to happen on this line:

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {"user_photos","user_about_me","friends_photos","user_status", "publish_stream"}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener()
```

The problem is, none of the functions are called (onComplete, onFacebookError, onError or onCancel)

which is strange, it just crashs on authorise. Tried this on all 3 of my devices one without facebook install and never had the app. Still crashes with the same error.

I call the facebook activity by doing the following:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, com.polygonattraction.lovebirds.facebook.GetFacebookToken.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, GET_FROM_FACEBOOK);
```

Any else have this bug/error and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you paste the full stack trace?

If it's a NPE on `facebook.authorize(...)`, then it's possible that you forgot to instantiate `facebook`.  Make sure you instantiate it in the beginning of your `onCreate` method.

```
    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("YOUR_APP_ID");
```

Also make sure you have included our Facebook Android SDK as a library in your project.

Comment: I'm on idiot I was trying to output the facebook.getaccesstoken() two days of being stuck! I gave you a +1 cause you help a lot.

Comment: No problem.  What was the actual problem?

Comment: The access token was expiring too fast.